# css property using html method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

any idea how to get css property using html method

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var ans=  $("#hello").html();
  console.log(ans);
});
```

```css
#hi{
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello">
  <div id="hi" >
    I am div
   </div>
 </div>
```

in this when i use html method `ans` doesn't contain `color:red`

```
 <div id="hi" style="red;">
   I am div
  </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: That would be the wrong method, you should use `css('color')` instead, and the element has no color, the child has

Comment: no you are not understanding

Comment: Confusing, but is this what you're looking for `var ans = $('#hello #hi').css('color');`?

Comment: you are get color then you can use inline css then you can get

Comment: @asprin: There's no purpose served by having the `#hello` part of that.

Comment: i have updated my answer.

Comment: why color is not getting using html method . since i have set the css property

Comment: @Mahi - `style="red"` doesn't do anything... it's not a CSS property.

Comment: var ans = $( "#hello" ).css( "color" );

Comment: Someone is deleting the comment?? i put mine but got deleted? why?

Comment: @Leothelion that was my another post that i have deleted. thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this when i use html method ans doesn't contain color:red

That's correct. It's because there's nothing in the DOM structure that's being converted to HTML by the `html` method that contains the color, because it's applied by the CSS stylesheet rules instead.

There is no built-in method in either the DOM or jQuery that will give you an HTML string that converts all of the currently-applied CSS style rules to inline `style` values. If you wanted something like that, you'd have to build it yourself, using (amongst other things) the `css` function (if you're building it with jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css style to your html tag like below, without css style declaration

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var ans = $("#hello").html();
  $('#hi').css('color','red');
  console.log(ans);
});
</script>
<div id="hello">
  <div id="hi" >
    I am div
   </div>
</div>
```